# Why Am I Getting a CoreAnimation Exception When I Try To Show A Modal View?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, core-animation

I am having a very weird problem with the following code:

```
#import "MainApplicationViewController.h"
#import "PasswordScreenViewController.h"

@implementation MainApplicationViewController

// The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"appHasBeenLaunchedBefore"] == NO){
        UIAlertView *firstLaunch = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set Password." message:@"This is the first time you launch the app. Would you like to set a password now?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [firstLaunch show];
        [firstLaunch release];
    }
}

/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIAlertViewDelegate Methods

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    //No = 0. Yes = 1.
    if(buttonIndex == 1) {
        PasswordScreenViewController *psvc = [[PasswordScreenViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentModalViewController:psvc animated:NO];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory Management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Go to my "UIAlertViewDelegate Methods pragma mark.

For some reason, I get the following message in the console whenever I try to show the modal view:

> CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: ***
>   -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument

Which makes no sense. I see no reason for it to pass a nil argument, specially since there is no particular possible cause that could prevent my object from being created. I have Googled like crazy in the last few days and I have NEVER seen anyone with this particular problem. If someone has any idea to fix it, please let me know, I am out of ideas, I don't know what else I could try, and it makes no sense.

Things I have tried so far:

- loadWithNibName:
- Try to show my modal view without calling an AlertView at all.

EDIT:

PasswordScreenView Implementation:

```
    //
//  PasswordScreenViewController.m
//
//  Created by  on 4/23/11.
//  Copyright 2011 . All rights reserved.
//

#import "PasswordScreenViewController.h"
#import <Security/Security.h>
#import "SFHFKeychainUtils.h"

@implementation PasswordScreenViewController
@synthesize p1, p2, p3, p4;
@synthesize vp1, vp2, vp3, vp4;
@synthesize delegate;

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    p1.text = @" ";
    p2.text = @" ";
    p3.text = @" ";
    p4.text = @" ";
    vp1.text = nil;
    vp2.text = nil;
    vp3.text = nil;
    vp4.text = nil;
    NSError *error;
    currentPassword = [NSString stringWithString:[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:@"user" andServiceName:@"com.atanacross.myprincesses.password" error:&error]];
    newPassword = [NSString stringWithString:nil];
    repeatNewPassword = [NSString stringWithString:nil];
    [p1 becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(id)initWithMode:(NSString *)mode
{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITextFieldDelegate Methods

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(range.length != 1)
    {
        if(textField == p1)
        {
            p1.text = string;
            vp1.text = string;
            [p2 becomeFirstResponder];
        }else if(textField == p2)
        {
            p2.text = string;
            vp2.text = string;
            [p3 becomeFirstResponder];
        }else if(textField == p3)
        {
            p3.text = string;
            vp3.text = string;
            [p4 becomeFirstResponder];
        }else if(textField == p4)
        {
            p4.text = string;
            vp4.text = string;
        }
    }else
    {
        if(textField == p4)
        {
            p4.text = @" ";
            vp4.text = nil;
            [p3 becomeFirstResponder];
        }else if(textField == p3)
        {
            p3.text = @" ";
            vp3.text = nil;
            [p2 becomeFirstResponder];
        }else if(textField == p2)
        {
            p2.text = @" ";
            vp2.text = nil;
            [p1 becomeFirstResponder];
        }else if(textField == p1)
        {
            p1.text = @" ";
            vp1.text = nil;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == vp1 || textField == vp2 || textField == vp3 || textField == vp4)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory Management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.p1 = nil;
    self.p2 = nil;
    self.p3 = nil;
    self.p4 = nil;
    self.vp1 = nil;
    self.vp2 = nil;
    self.vp3 = nil;
    self.vp4 = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [p1 release];
    [p2 release];
    [p3 release];
    [p4 release];
    [vp1 release];
    [vp2 release];
    [vp3 release];
    [vp4 release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: I think we need to see your `PasswordScreenViewController` implementation.

Comment: I’m not sure, but you are not allowed to display the AlertView in viewDidLoad. Try calling it in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

Comment: I have added the implementation for PasswordScreenViewController. Sorry for taking so long. I think Marcelo could be right, so I will try that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newPassword = [NSString stringWithString:nil];
repeatNewPassword = [NSString stringWithString:nil];
```

This is what you're looking for. Try initializing with `newPassword = nil` or `newPassword = @""`.

Comment: I don't know how that could fix my problem though? I tried it anyways, but I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: Oh never mind! You are a freaking genius haha. Why exactly was this stopping? The two recommended strings didn't solve my problem. It's actually currentPassword. I did what you said in current password to test and it kinda makes sense, because currentPassword gets nil when there is no password. Thanks a bunch for your solution, can't believe how fast you got it considering I asked in many other places days ago and no one was able to answer it. Thanks a bunch, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was answered but would like to remark that I also had a problem like this:

**CoreAnimation: ignoring exception**

Also with origin in an action taken inside an UIAlertViewDelegate method.

This is a bit tricky since I would suppose that the error was related with some animation stuff or something in the UI, but the error had nothing to do with that, just something in my code, as in this question.

So if you see this error, it means that the app should have crashed and terminated but for some reason it is not terminated (which makes more difficult to trace...). Forget about the CoreAnimation and start debuging ! :p